# Parity in the Schrödinger equation of the hydrogen atom

Tags: physics, quantum-mechanics, parity, even-and-odd-functions

Hi I'm studying quantum mechanics with Stephen Gasiorowicz's book.

It says for the $n=2$ states of the hydrogen atom, the $l=0$ state has even parity and the $l=1$ state has odd parity.

As far as I know is, the parity transform changes the sign of the spatial component so that $r$ should be $-r$.

And if the sign of the function does not change by this transformation, it is even and if it changes, it is odd.

However, the Schrödinger equations are given by:
$$\phi_{200}=(2a_{0})^{-3/2}2(1-\frac{r}{2a_{0}})e^{-r/2a_{0}}Y_{00}$$
$$\phi_{211}=(2a_{0})^{-3/2}3^{-1/2}(\frac{r}{a_0})e^{-r/2a_{0}}Y_{11}$$
$$\phi_{210}=(2a_{0})^{-3/2}3^{-1/2}(\frac{r}{a_0})e^{-r/2a_{0}}Y_{10}$$
$$\phi_{21-1}=(2a_{0})^{-3/2}3^{-1/2}(\frac{r}{a_0})e^{-r/2a_{0}}Y_{1-1}$$

For $l=0$, $\quad \phi_{200}(-r)=(2a_{0})^{-3/2}2(1+\frac{r}{2a_{0}})e^{r/2a_{0}}Y_{00} \neq \phi_{200}(r)$.

For $l=1$, $\quad \phi_{21m}(-r)=(2a_{0})^{-3/2}3^{-1/2}(\frac{-r}{a_0})e^{r/2a_{0}}Y_{1m} \neq -\phi_{21m}(r)$

But why do you say these have even parity and odd parity respectively?

Please correct me if I'm misunderstanding something.

Thank you.

Comment: You must change $(r,\theta,\phi)$ to $(r,\pi-\theta,\phi+\pi)$, not $r$ to $-r$.

Comment: You change $\vec r$ to $-\vec r$. In your notation $r$ is the magnitude, and does not change

Comment: @Gonçalo Oh, I was thinking wrong. Thanks for the correction!

Comment: @Andrei I forgot that r stands for magnitude, thanks for letting me know :)